# Error QGIS 2threejs subdivided DTM

Tags: dem, qgis2threejs

I am trying to figure out how to work with qgis2threejs plugin. Since I would like to be able to export as glTF file a an area with DTM and Orto as overlay (texture), I decided to begin by working on a small portion with 2 micro DTM and their respective ortho.  Unfortunately as soon as I open the DTM on ThreeJS plug-in it shows an empty area between DTM 1 and 2 even if their border should coincide. As showed in the shared Image [error tiled DTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqA2L.jpg) border are shown as not continuous, with a GAP which doesn't allow me  to proceed with my research.

[image]

---

I have extracted the DTM file from a larger DTM. My goal is to be able to export a 10 square kilometers area. Unfortunately exporting the whole area cause the Orto to loose much of its original detail and this is why I am trying to figure out how be able to export little chunks of the area. I seek a way to reach my goal without subdividing the DTM.